# How to change CSS to the same class but another input name

Tags: php, css

I have 5 buttons on my page and I want to style their CSS so they would be different,
I don't know how to do that.
Here is the code:

```
<input input class='field' type='button' name='a4' value='A4'/>
<input input class='field' type='button' name='a3' value='A3'/>
<input input class='field' type='button' name='a2' value='A2'/>
<input input class='field' type='button' name='a1' value='A1'/>
<input input class='field' type='button' name='a'  value='A'/>
```

should CSS looks like this:

```
.field {
    width: 120px;
}

.field a1 {
    width: 220px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [attribute selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869405%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```css
.field[name='a1'] {
    color: blue;
}
```

It is very [well-supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2) across all major browsers. A demo is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/sMuAS/).